# How can I nicely typeset this MySql query with the listings package?

Tags: listings, width

I am trying to show output of MySql explain in my LaTeX document. I am using `listings` package to make listings.
Sample LaTeX code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL,caption={SQL query explained}]
mysql> explain 
    select dd.data from dane dd 
      join test1.tag1 t1 on dd.id = t1.id 
      join test1.tag2 t2 on dd.id = t2.id 
      join test1.tag3 t3 on dd.id = t3.id 
      join test1.tag4 t4 on dd.id = t4.id 
      join test1.tag5 t5 on dd.id = t5.id 
      join test1.tag6 t6 on dd.id = t6.id 
      join test1.tag7 t7 on dd.id = t7.id 
      join test1.tag8 t8 on dd.id = t8.id 
      join test1.tag9 t9 on dd.id = t9.id 
      join test1.tag10 t10 on dd.id = t10.id 
    where t1.val = 1 
      and t2.val = 2 
      and t3.val = 3 
      and t4.val = 4 
      and t5.val = 5 
      and t6.val = 6 
      and t7.val = 7 
      and t8.val = 8 
      and t9.val = 9 
      and t10.val = 10 ;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra                                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 99901 | Parent of 10 pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t1.id,const |     1 | Child of 't1' in pushed join@1                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t2.id,const |     1 | Child of 't2' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t4    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t3.id,const |     1 | Child of 't3' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t5    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t4.id,const |     1 | Child of 't4' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t6    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t1.id,const |     1 | Child of 't5' in pushed join@1                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t7    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t5.id,const |     1 | Child of 't6' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t8    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t7.id,const |     1 | Child of 't7' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t9    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t5.id,const |     1 | Child of 't8' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t10   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t8.id,const |     1 | Child of 't9' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dd    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test1.t5.id       |     1 | Using where                                                   |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
\end{lstlisting}
```

And the pdf result:
[image: pdf result]

There are two issues:
1. Text is too wide to fit page.
2. In LaTeX source white spaces are used to arrange data columns. In pdf output there are truncated.

I will appreciate any ideas how to deal with this issues and transform explain output to viewable form in pdf.

Comment: As `lstlisting` is intended for code not for table you must remove the table from the code and just render the table as usual.

Comment: Adding the option `basicstyle=\ttfamily` fixes the variable spaces, and `breaklines=true` allows `listings` to insert line breaks where appropriate, but that breaks up the alignment.

Comment: @alexwlchan I have added `basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily` which makes text small enough to fit page without line break, but still multiple spaces are merged into one.

Comment: @MichałHerman Try to also add the `columns=fixed` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this listing is particularly wide, you should

- set a small font size by passing, for instance, `\tiny` to the `basicstyle` key;
- present the listing in landscape orientation by using, for instance, the `landscape` environment provided by the `pdflscape` package.

Furthermore, to make sure that spaces are respected (roughly speaking), you should

- switch to a monospace font (instead of a proportional one, which is the default) by passing `\ttfamily` to the `basicstyle` key;
- use the `columns=fixed` option (for more details, see 2.10 in the `listings` manual).

However, if you use the Computer Modern or Latin Modern fonts, your `SQL` keywords won't be typeset in boldface, because those fonts don't comprise a typewriter font in bold series. To remedy that problem, you can always switch to some font that does, such as Courier (as shown below) or Bera Mono.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\lstdefinestyle{SQL-Michalstyle}
{%
  language   = SQL,
  caption    = {SQL query explained},
  basicstyle = \tiny\ttfamily,
  columns    = fixed,
}

\lstset{style=SQL-Michalstyle}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}
\begin{lstlisting}
mysql> explain 
    select dd.data from dane dd 
      join test1.tag1 t1 on dd.id = t1.id 
      join test1.tag2 t2 on dd.id = t2.id 
      join test1.tag3 t3 on dd.id = t3.id 
      join test1.tag4 t4 on dd.id = t4.id 
      join test1.tag5 t5 on dd.id = t5.id 
      join test1.tag6 t6 on dd.id = t6.id 
      join test1.tag7 t7 on dd.id = t7.id 
      join test1.tag8 t8 on dd.id = t8.id 
      join test1.tag9 t9 on dd.id = t9.id 
      join test1.tag10 t10 on dd.id = t10.id 
    where t1.val = 1 
      and t2.val = 2 
      and t3.val = 3 
      and t4.val = 4 
      and t5.val = 5 
      and t6.val = 6 
      and t7.val = 7 
      and t8.val = 8 
      and t9.val = 9 
      and t10.val = 10 ;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra                                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 99901 | Parent of 10 pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t1.id,const |     1 | Child of 't1' in pushed join@1                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t2.id,const |     1 | Child of 't2' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t4    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t3.id,const |     1 | Child of 't3' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t5    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t4.id,const |     1 | Child of 't4' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t6    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t1.id,const |     1 | Child of 't5' in pushed join@1                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t7    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t5.id,const |     1 | Child of 't6' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t8    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t7.id,const |     1 | Child of 't7' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t9    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t5.id,const |     1 | Child of 't8' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t10   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | test1.t8.id,const |     1 | Child of 't9' in pushed join@1; Using where                   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dd    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test1.t5.id       |     1 | Using where                                                   |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.01 sec)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```